# Multiseat sometimes not working

Tags: nvidia, multiseat

I have two working seat, seat0 and seat1. Both working properly. But sometimes the seat1 login screen don't come from reboot. Seat0 working properly while seat1 screen say's no hdmi connected.

I am useing nvidia gt1030 with seat1 and igpu with seat0. For software site I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS branch with no modification with Display Manager. Also I config this setup from debian multiseat wiki page.

I tested that when I stop supply power to my cpu tower for a while and then boot, seat1 started working. So basically first boot always work for both seat, 2nd+ boot don't work for seat1. Also note seat1's mouse and keybord working properly for subsequent boot. Only display says no HDMI.

**How Can I debug it?**

Answer (score 0):

When the display stops working for seat1, does the output of `loginctl seat-status seat1` still indicate that video port still belongs to seat1?  Even without multiseat, I often had to "[Drain the Capacitors](https://fosscoder.blogspot.com/2015/06/dont-ever-forget-to-drain-capacitors.html)" to get a monitor working via a video card.